# SSIS XML Source component

Tags: xml, ssis, xsd

I am using `XML Source` component to read and `xml` file, and based on the provided `xsd` file the data is retrieved and populated into a sql server table.

I noticed that even the `xml` file does not match the schema defined in the `xsd` completely, still the matching `xml` elements are read by the `XML Source` component and can be loaded to the database.

What I exactly want is, if the `xml` and `xsd` do not match 100%, the `XML Source` component should fail as a whole, even if there is a correct element that can be matched ?

Comment: The phrases 'does not match...completely' and 'do not match 100%' are not clear enough. Please provide full examples, with XML and XSD, for each problem scenario.

Comment: If you want to validate an XML file against XSD, you can do it by using SSIS XML Task, Operation Validation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/validate-xml-with-the-xml-task?view=sql-server-ver15